# A pronuncia de "Lho" pode ser entendida como "Lio" ou é um som único?

Tags: pronúncia

Minha duvida é a seguinte:

> Quando falamos "Lho", nós estamos produzindo um som único, ou na realidade só estamos falando "Lio" de maneira rápida? Ex: Bara**lho** e Bara**lio**.

Motivo: Eu estava tentando explicar a pronúncia de algumas palavras do Português para uma amiga do Japão, porém no Japonês é impossível reproduzir sons "Lho", "Cri", "Nha". Porém ao tentar, eu percebi que "lho" é muito similar a "lio"(mas pronunciado rapidamente), "cri" é similar a "kiri", "Nha" é similar a "Nia", etc.

A minha duvida é, eles são apenas similares ou realmente são os mesmos som? 
**"Crime" e "Kirime"**   apenas soam parecido, ou são o exato mesmo som?(Portanto que Kiri seja pronunciado de maneira rápida o bastante).

Eu sei que fui alfabetizado a entender "Crime" como 2 sílabas, mas me pergunto se de maneira subjetiva, "kirime" estaria realmente incorreto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lho* e *lio* têm sons diferentes como também *nho* e *nio* soam diferente.

O som do *lh* é /ʎ/, o qual é produzido quase como um *l* mas com os dos lados da língua nas partes laterais do paladar (por isso o som chama-se *aproximante **lateral** palatal*).

O som do *li* mais qualquer vogal (e sem hiato) é /lj/, onde primeiro soa /l/ e depois a semivogal /j/ que forma diptongo com a vogal seguinte.

O que acontece é que, em alguns dialetos, por um processo chamado *assimilação*, é possível o /l/ sofrer uma modificação, lateralizando-se parcialmente. Isto ocorre porque a forma de articulação de /j/ sói ser mais lateral. Mas neste caso, embora o som /j/ segue, pode realizar-se de forma mais ligeira com o qual é muito difícil perceber a diferença.

Comment: Que legal, era bem esse tipo de resposta mais "técnica" que eu estava esperando!

Comment: A resposta está claríssima, sim.